# ¿cómo puedo rellenar cada polígono con el color de los puntos?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Tengo un gráfico con tres polígonos a los cuales quisiera colocarles relleno de color para cada uno de ellos. Soy principiante en el lenguaje de R y ya he buscado varios ejemplos pero ninguno me ha funcionado.

Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
hull <- datpca %>%group_by(condition) %>%slice(chull(x=PC1,y=PC2))
P + geom_polygon(data = hull, alpha = 0.5, fill="#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07")
```

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Se supone que cada área tendrá un color, para que `ggplot` determine el color que le corresponde a cada área, claramente hay que decirle de dónde mapear el sombreado (`fill`), eso dependerá en tu caso, pero imagino que la variable que establece esto es `condition`:

```
geom_polygon(data = hull, 
             aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, fill = condition, group = condition), 
             alpha = 0.5) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))
```

La configuración del color va por otro camino, en este caso por `scale_fill_manual()`